# How to associate downloadable product to configurable products in magento

Tags: magento-1.7, configurable-product, downloadable

I have a product with two format one downloadable and another non-downloadeable. How can I show both format together on frontend with that product.

Answer (score 1):

By default the Configurable product only allows simple and virtual products to be used, this is specified in the config.xml in Mage/Catalog/etc/:

```
<configurable translate="label" module="catalog">
   <label>Configurable Product</label>
   <model>catalog/product_type_configurable</model>
   <price_model>catalog/product_type_configurable_price</price_model>
   <composite>1</composite>
   <allow_product_types>
       <simple/>
       <virtual/>
   </allow_product_types>
   <index_priority>30</index_priority>
   <price_indexer>catalog/product_indexer_price_configurable</price_indexer>
```

To add a downloadable product to you configuration you have to create a small extension (do not change the core file!) to add this option:

Module init file (app/etc/modules/Example_DownloadableConfigurable.xml):

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Example_DownloadableConfigurable>
            <active>true</active>
            <codePool>community</codePool>
            <depends>
                <Mage_Bundle/>
                <Mage_Downloadable/>
            </depends>
        </Example_DownloadableConfigurable>
    </modules>
</config>
```

Module configuration file (app/code/community/Example/DownloadableConfigurable/etc/config.xml):

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Example_DownloadableConfigurable>
            <version>14.293.1</version>
        </Example_DownloadableConfigurable>
    </modules>

    <global>
        <catalog>
            <product>
                <type>
                    <configurable>
                        <allowed_selection_types>
                            <downloadable/>
                        </allowed_selection_types>
                    </configurable>
                </type>
            </product>
        </catalog>
    </global>
</config>
```

Just tested this with an order and the downloadable product is added to the list with My Downloadable products. The code above can also be applied to the bundle products type (just change `<configurable>` to `<bundle>`).

Comment: Thank You for your answer. I did as you told but there is no change.

Comment: You have to create an attribute that is used for a configurable product, assign that to both the downloadable and the non-downloadable product (for example: order_type with values Download or Shipping). If you now create a configurable product based on that attribute you will have the option to include both products

Comment: Also refresh the cache to rebuild the configuration

Comment: It works first time but when I go to downloadable product and  set "Links can be purchased separately" option to YES. then this downloadable products disapperars from the list in configurable product associate list and then if I set "Links can be purchased separately" again to "No" then downloadable products still does not show in list. Why.?

Comment: Yes, its not possible to use the option that links can be purchased separately, not sure why the file isn't shown when you set it back to no, maybe you need to reindex/flush cache?

Comment: I have refreshed cache and reindexed but no effect.

Comment: Also when I choose downloadable product and ordered it then in customer email there is no link to download. can you tell me why it is happening.?

Comment: The link is not included in the e-mail because Magento doesn't support this, the file is listed in my downloads in the account menu.

Answer (score 0):

shashank you can do this by xml configuration:

Magento provide two type of `product in associate  list for configurable product`s.One is `simple and other is virtual`

```
                               <configurable translate="label" module="catalog">
                <label>Configurable Product</label>
                <model>catalog/product_type_configurable</model>
                <price_model>catalog/product_type_configurable_price</price_model>
                <composite>1</composite>
                <allow_product_types>
                    <simple/>
        <!-- add this here -->
        <downloadable/>
                    <virtual/>
                </allow_product_types>
                <index_priority>30</index_priority>
                <price_indexer>catalog/product_indexer_price_configurable</price_indexer>
            </configurable>
```

Comment: Thank you Amit for you answer but I am unable to understand your answer that in which xml file I have to do changes and what code I have to add at which place. Please do more clear.

Comment: Change in config.xml  of mage/catalog/etc

Comment: Hello Amit I have changed there. but when I go to Associate Products tab in configurable product then there is no name of downloadble product in list.

Comment: I will check..shortly